# Kudan AR development key not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kudan

I am using Kudan SDK 1.4.1 and Android studio 2.2.2

I have created an empty project named "ar" with a package 'eu.kudan.ar', added KudanAR.aar library and created a simple Activity:

```
package eu.kudan.ar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import eu.kudan.kudan.ARAPIKey;
import eu.kudan.kudan.ARActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ARActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ARAPIKey key = ARAPIKey.getInstance();
        key.setAPIKey("...api key from kudan wiki...");
        System.out.println(key.licenseKeyIsValid());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I copied the long 1.4 License key from [kudan wiki](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys) (also tried with other older keys). The app compiles and starts but immediately reports `Your API key is not valid.`. Tried on both, device and emulator.

What should I do to make the key working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudan SDK 1.4.1 Api key has changed.

`sVmoznmKZ+4nFEHD6HoslwpC26PNuBZGHrikUwyon2BKSvza1yu2CqbSrae+pHPr1NHjhsf5pHQOZn8IEqXlqXFodGsrOJhxJANbMOdvnRLUi9/QWGqyRL9FViDmyohw6e5R7U4Ex8H7d7spLLvhfp5HFv56DgLr8c8sC2ipDtv9g1IjOTaY7UGxata3eulG2A/UkIdRv2NcotZXqan01xQUWFAislEwlGguParEYiwu11T4mqtU3dQBbfxpvxbczjdYz493YG3rAO2RHgT+5M5TJShJsz2irkNo71JD2Fzqf4AR2b4+7t1c55zKjegXzGS6Xa/rpNn9yiXUn7rUYIHNvN3cEQa9HsZiVxAV4vJgxFS+T/AxfWqKrEg1uj6xF5MsodZ2EkZ8mqliYIsxZqnFz+Re2HeWG8wvrEob0ZwRIO0TxppAemZc3HChTAPLcNt5gzeBk0oRP4wnrFAFFBDi8XjDocwTSVw++hWZb1qNHzt6bKLsMDRT057UVuuZB6M8f7EOQD79Oah0Vrx/3DUK6e9BEV8oGFNHtk1wyYEkg0i6RLhVSokGx//Qj36A4gCz3h1OjtfB0OuukbNq7xI1L/FcNQLmGYNGZwszARjGr9ESw1gVAkbQMxaV27uo/KoIq4+nR7RL8iT7t7NAaXCFIi24RR+7WGjTvKqWYjA=`

link: https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys